# É possível me conectar em uma VPN via código C#?

Tags: c#, vpn

Minha maquina de trabalho acessa a VPN da empresa, e quando eu rodo os *Console application* na minha maquina, preciso estar conectado a ela pois o IP do banco(10.0.0.7) só é acessível via VPN.

O problema é, a internet SEMPRE CAI, e eu tenho que ir de forma **manual** conectar a VPN novamente, segue a imagem do processo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, preciso da interação humana, pois quando a internet cai, consequentemente a VPN cai, e eu preciso clicar em conectar.

É possível fazer essa conexão via código? assim eu não preciso mais colocar a mão nisso.

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar ligar usando um processo externo

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "a_minha_ligacao utilizador palavra-passe");
```